# How to attach FrameworkContentElement to MVVM Light EventToCommand

Tags: wpf, devexpress, mvvm-light

I'm trying to convert an event to a command on a devexpress wpf grid context menu item which is derived from FrameworkContentElement instead of FrameworkElement. This causes a runtime error :

{"Cannot attach type \"EventToCommand\" to type \"BarButtonItem\". Instances of type \"EventToCommand\" can only be attached to objects of type \"FrameworkElement\"."}

Is there any workaround?

```
<dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
    <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="deleteRowItem" Content="Delete" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ItemClick">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding FooChangeCommand}"
                PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </dxb:BarButtonItem>

    <!--ItemClick="deleteRowItem_ItemClick"/>-->
</dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
```

Unfortunately devexpress have run into problems changing the base class to FrameworkElement having intended to make that change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FrameworkConentElement` is a class that is only available in WPF and not in Silverlight. As MVVM Light is intended to provide a common functionality for **all** WPF dialects *(WPF 3.5, WPF 4, Silverlight 3, Silverlight 4, Sivlverlight 5, WP 7, WP 7.1)* it cannot include an implementation that only works in one of the frameworks.

For a discussion about the differences between `FrameworkElement` and `FrameworkContentElement` [see here](http://wpfdisciples.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/frameworkelement-vs-frameworkcontentelement/).

However, you can just easily implement your own `EventToCommand` class supporting `ContentElement` (from which `FrameworkContentElement` inherits). The class was copied from BL0015 of the MVVM Light source code and modified:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This <see cref="System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction" /> can be
    /// used to bind any event on any FrameworkElement to an <see cref="ICommand" />.
    /// Typically, this element is used in XAML to connect the attached element
    /// to a command located in a ViewModel. This trigger can only be attached
    /// to a FrameworkElement or a class deriving from FrameworkElement.
    /// <para>To access the EventArgs of the fired event, use a RelayCommand&lt;EventArgs&gt;
    /// and leave the CommandParameter and CommandParameterValue empty!</para>
    /// </summary>
    ////[ClassInfo(typeof(EventToCommand),
    ////  VersionString = "3.0.0.0",
    ////  DateString = "201003041420",
    ////  Description = "A Trigger used to bind any event to an ICommand.",
    ////  UrlContacts = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/6955785/266919",
    ////  Email = "")]
    public partial class EventToCommandWpf : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the EventArgs passed to the
        /// event handler will be forwarded to the ICommand's Execute method
        /// when the event is fired (if the bound ICommand accepts an argument
        /// of type EventArgs).
        /// <para>For example, use a RelayCommand&lt;MouseEventArgs&gt; to get
        /// the arguments of a MouseMove event.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public bool PassEventArgsToCommand
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides a simple way to invoke this trigger programatically
        /// without any EventArgs.
        /// </summary>
        public void Invoke()
        {
            Invoke(null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the trigger.
        /// <para>To access the EventArgs of the fired event, use a RelayCommand&lt;EventArgs&gt;
        /// and leave the CommandParameter and CommandParameterValue empty!</para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">The EventArgs of the fired event.</param>
        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            if (AssociatedElementIsDisabled())
            {
                return;
            }

            var command = GetCommand();
            var commandParameter = CommandParameterValue;

            if (commandParameter == null
                 && PassEventArgsToCommand)
            {
                commandParameter = parameter;
            }

            if (command != null
                 && command.CanExecute(commandParameter))
            {
                command.Execute(commandParameter);
            }
        }

        private static void OnCommandChanged(
             EventToCommandWpf element,
             DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.OldValue != null)
            {
                ((ICommand)e.OldValue).CanExecuteChanged -= element.OnCommandCanExecuteChanged;
            }

            var command = (ICommand)e.NewValue;

            if (command != null)
            {
                command.CanExecuteChanged += element.OnCommandCanExecuteChanged;
            }

            element.EnableDisableElement();
        }

        private bool AssociatedElementIsDisabled()
        {
            var element = GetAssociatedObject();
            return AssociatedObject == null
                 || (element != null
                     && !element.IsEnabled);
        }

        private void EnableDisableElement()
        {
            var element = GetAssociatedObject();

            if (element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var command = this.GetCommand();

            if (this.MustToggleIsEnabledValue
                 && command != null)
            {
                SetIsEnabled(element, command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameterValue));  
            }
        }

        private void OnCommandCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnableDisableElement();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <see cref="CommandParameter" /> dependency property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
             "CommandParameter",
             typeof(object),
             typeof(EventToCommandWpf),
             new PropertyMetadata(
                  null,
                  (s, e) => {
                      var sender = s as EventToCommandWpf;
                      if (sender == null)
                      {
                          return;
                      }

                      if (sender.AssociatedObject == null)
                      {
                          return;
                      }

                      sender.EnableDisableElement();
                  }));

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <see cref="Command" /> dependency property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
             "Command",
             typeof(ICommand),
             typeof(EventToCommandWpf),
             new PropertyMetadata(
                  null,
                  (s, e) => OnCommandChanged(s as EventToCommandWpf, e)));

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <see cref="MustToggleIsEnabled" /> dependency property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MustToggleIsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
             "MustToggleIsEnabled",
             typeof(bool),
             typeof(EventToCommandWpf),
             new PropertyMetadata(
                  false,
                  (s, e) => {
                      var sender = s as EventToCommandWpf;
                      if (sender == null)
                      {
                          return;
                      }

                      if (sender.AssociatedObject == null)
                      {
                          return;
                      }

                      sender.EnableDisableElement();
                  }));

        private object _commandParameterValue;

        private bool? _mustToggleValue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the ICommand that this trigger is bound to. This
        /// is a DependencyProperty.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets an object that will be passed to the <see cref="Command" />
        /// attached to this trigger. This is a DependencyProperty.
        /// </summary>
        public object CommandParameter
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets an object that will be passed to the <see cref="Command" />
        /// attached to this trigger. This property is here for compatibility
        /// with the Silverlight version. This is NOT a DependencyProperty.
        /// For databinding, use the <see cref="CommandParameter" /> property.
        /// </summary>
        public object CommandParameterValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this._commandParameterValue ?? this.CommandParameter;
            }

            set
            {
                _commandParameterValue = value;
                EnableDisableElement();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the attached element must be
        /// disabled when the <see cref="Command" /> property's CanExecuteChanged
        /// event fires. If this property is true, and the command's CanExecute 
        /// method returns false, the element will be disabled. If this property
        /// is false, the element will not be disabled when the command's
        /// CanExecute method changes. This is a DependencyProperty.
        /// </summary>
        public bool MustToggleIsEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)this.GetValue(MustToggleIsEnabledProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                SetValue(MustToggleIsEnabledProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the attached element must be
        /// disabled when the <see cref="Command" /> property's CanExecuteChanged
        /// event fires. If this property is true, and the command's CanExecute 
        /// method returns false, the element will be disabled. This property is here for
        /// compatibility with the Silverlight version. This is NOT a DependencyProperty.
        /// For databinding, use the <see cref="MustToggleIsEnabled" /> property.
        /// </summary>
        public bool MustToggleIsEnabledValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this._mustToggleValue == null
                              ? this.MustToggleIsEnabled
                              : this._mustToggleValue.Value;
            }

            set
            {
                _mustToggleValue = value;
                EnableDisableElement();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when this trigger is attached to a DependencyObject.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            EnableDisableElement();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is here for compatibility
        /// with the Silverlight version.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The object to which this trigger
        /// is attached casted as a FrameworkElement.</returns>
        private IInputElement GetAssociatedObject()
        {
            return AssociatedObject as IInputElement;
        }

        private void SetIsEnabled(IInputElement element, bool value)
        {
            if (element is UIElement)
            {
                ((UIElement)element).IsEnabled = value;
            }
            else if (element is ContentElement)
            {
                ((ContentElement)element).IsEnabled = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot set IsEnabled. Element is neither ContentElemen, nor UIElement.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is here for compatibility
        /// with the Silverlight version.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The command that must be executed when
        /// this trigger is invoked.</returns>
        private ICommand GetCommand()
        {
            return Command;
        }
    }
}
```

To inlcude it into your code you have to define a xml namespace pointing to the correct dll and then use it just like the normal `EventToCommand` class.

**NOTE: This class does not work in Silverlight!**

Comment: ahah thanks for that. I managed to work around by using the InvokeCommandAction from System.Windows.Interactivity which doesn't seem to have the same limitation (although it doesn't marshall params). However I'm still stuck as it turns out the popup Item I've now bound is on a completely different visual tree to my app, so I can't work out how to bind to my viewmodel!

Comment: As an aside, why does InvokeCommandAction not have the limitation of only working with FrameworkElement - is it not silverlight compatible?

Comment: Dont't know the implementation of it, but I guess hat it des not need the IsEnabled property as EventToComand des.

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to solve this specific issue using dev express, this will do the trick!

```
<dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
   <dxb:BarButtonItem Name="deleteRowItem" Content="Delete" Command="{Binding View.DataContext.DeleteSelectionCommand}" />
</dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
```

I was following their example which had an event on the button, little realising there was also a command I could use. Then the challenge was working out the binding as the menu item is not on the main visual tree. However the above solves that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work with DEV express

```
 <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="123" Name="item1">
                <dxmvvm:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="ItemClick" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=item1, Path=Content}"/>
                </dxmvvm:Interaction.Triggers>
            </dxb:BarButtonItem>
```